# How to accept only 15 characters in a form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a function like this:

```
function validateInput() {
    var search_text = document.getElementById('search_text').value;
    var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('sb_search');
    var filter = /^[\x20-\x7E]*$/;

    if (filter.test(search_text) && search_text.length>0){
        return true;
    }

    else if (filter.test(size) && search_text.length>0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    } 
}
```

I want to return true only when the search_text is not empty, satisfy the regex and is not more than 15 characters. How can I do that? 1st and 2nd is already done.

Comment: if(search_text.length != 15) {return false;}

Comment: Why can't you just specify `maxlength="15"` on the `<input>`?

Comment: You already seem to be using a RegEx, why wouldn't you just limit the input to, 15 characters that way.  I really hope this isn't trying to limit a user's password length.  I really hate when websites do that.  If I want a 30 character password I should be able to use it.

Comment: @Ramhound: I tried that in the first place. No it's to limit the search box. Can you please help me modify my Regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
          function validateInput() {
            var search_text = document.getElementById('search_text').value;
            var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
            var submitButton = document.getElementById('sb_search');
            var filter = /^[\x20-\x7E]*$/;

            if (filter.test(search_text) && search_text.length>0){
                return true;
            }

            else if (filter.test(size) && search_text.length>0){
                return true;
            }


            else if(search_text.length>=15){
                 return false;
                 } 

             }
```

Comment: Didn't work. Help me modify my regex to only accept 15 characters then I will accept your answer.

Comment: ^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{8,15}$ perfect regex for you...http://rubular.com/r/J9FF4iCXjr

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want to like this

```
 if (filter.test(search_text) && search_text.length>0 && search_text.length<= 15)
      {
           return true;
      }
 else
           return false
```